# Bootstrap responsive col alignment with overlay image in center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, alignment

Have problem with responsive div alignment using bootstrap.
Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-5">
            <img src="/images/big_img.jpg}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 vs">
            <img src="/images/small_img.jpg}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-5">
            <img src="/images/big_img.jpg}"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    text-align: center;
}
.col-xl-5 {
    display:inline-block;
}

.col-xl-2 {
    display:inline-block;
}

.vs img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

### And as result i have this on full screen:

[image: full screen alignment]

### And this on small:

[image: small screen alignment]

### Need something like this on full scree:

[image: need full screen alignment]

### And in small resolution:

[image: need small screen alignment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with the responsive margin utils (`mx-xl-n5`, `mx-0`, `my-xl-0`, `my-n5`, etc..). Negative margins will create the overlay effect in the center.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xl text-center text-xl-right my-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/300"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-auto text-center mx-xl-n5 px-1 mx-0 my-xl-0 my-n5 vs">
            <img src="//placehold.it/100/22cc22"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl text-center text-xl-left my-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/300"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/VaALMWei4G